# trying to find memory leaks in my c++ code

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks

I am trying to find memory leaks in my c++ code but so far i have used VALGRIND and when i run the line-

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes example1
```

The terminal just doesnt proceed it displays 3 lines and the cursor just blinks at a new line showing that it is either stuck or still running and i have to press Ctrl + C for the process to quit and then it displays LEAK SUMMARY, I'm not sure if this is how it works but some direction would be helpful

Comment: What would your program normally do when run with no arguments? Is it waiting for input?  `valgrind` doesn't change what it does. It _does_ make it run much slower though. Maybe you need to give it some input, or just be more patient.

Comment: my program is a server using libhttpserver (available on github) it runs a server on port 8080 and waits for client requests and when i send requests, they are displayed on the terminal when i run the "valgrind" command but when i press Ctrl + C it then shows all the MEMORY LEAKS, is this how it works ? I have tried waiting for 40 mins.

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected. Leaks are only shown after the process exits, not while it's still running.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is working as expected. Reporting memory leaks only happens after the process exits, not while it's still running.

Other kinds of memory errors will be shown as soon as they happen, such as reading uninitialized memory, or accessing memory after it's been deallocated. But not memory leaks.

So if the process is still running, you need to tell it to exit. Do that however you would normally tell it to exit when not running under valgrind, e.g. send it a signal. That's what Ctrl-C does.